# Problem with Pyinstaller when using ITKPython

Tags: python, pyinstaller, itk

I am using ITKPython,
My codes are working well in PyCharm with *.py format but after making a standalone *.exe file via PyInstaller some errors occure as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “RSG_V_0.py”, line 27, in <module>
File “site-packages\itkExtras.py”, line 449, in imread
File “site-packages\itkLazy.py”, line 40, in getattribute
AttributeError: ‘LazyITKModule’ object has no attribute ‘ImageFileReader’
[29316] Failed to execute script RSG_V_0
```

Would you please show me the way to solve these kind of problems.
By the way, already I test my PyInstaller with a simple print.py, In fact PyInstaller is working correctly without ITK filters.

Thanks
Sina

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely a problem in PyInstaller. Report it on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I reported just now.